# BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP LOG master

Tags: sql-server

I am facing the below error in logs and observed that the Master log backup is failing.

DB Version - SQL server 13

OS Version - 2012 R2

Master DB Recovery Model - Full

Error -

Message
BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP LOG master. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.

Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Only a full database backup can be performed on the master database.

I don't know why your master database is set to full recovery, but that is (as far as I can tell) a non-standard configuration. Given the above, I'd consider setting it to simple recovery.

Comment: Thank you so much, your comments made me to review the current back up settings.